# jquery textbox need to work on load

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a solution like,
I have 2 textbox with start and end date, I need my start textbox with empty and end date with todays date now both comes with todays date.

When page loads first time start date textbox empty and end date with todays date after the event fires for a search start date comes with whatever the date selected for.

I am looking like something like `if(!postback)` in asp.net ie, only that will occure very first time the page load.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: why dont you set dates from code behind ?

Comment: Some one else did that already....i cant modify that....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use a TempData flag every time your page will be posted back. All values inside TempData will be erased after read first time.

Comment: what is TempData ? could you put a link about this ? or explain more ? how to set data on it ? or how to read that ?

Comment: Since your are using asp .net its a built-in class. you can put data for be read the next time the action will be called, when it will be automatically clear.

    TempData["loadedFirstTime"] = true;

then where the action is called you can do something like

    ViewBag.FillDate = TempData["loadedFirstTime"] == true ? true:false;

Comment: you are talking about `WebViewPage.TempData` in mvc ? the question is about the recognition a `PostBack` on client, not server side !!

Comment: TempData is for asp.net MVC don't know that he's using MVC

Comment: yes, my bad, I thought you had access to server side and asp .net had tempData as well asp .net mvc

Answer (score 0):

if you have `PostBack` on your page, JavaScript `Load` event will be fire every time, and entire js and markup will make again... you need to create a flag, on a something like a `HiddenField` to post to server and keeps his value when your page back to client, and every time in load event in javascript, read value you had set on `HiddenField` to find, is a `PostBack`, or not